# Enabling Virtualization (SVM Mode) Causing AMD 7900x Graphics Driver to Fail

Tags: drivers, bios, virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux, amd-ryzen

I recently built a desktop PC with an AMD 7900X CPU and a Gigabyte B650 Aorus Elite AX motherboard. It is running Windows 11, and I have not installed an external PCIe graphics card. The BIOS settings are set to default. Initially, everything, including the graphics card, worked perfectly. However, I encountered an issue when I enabled the "SVM Mode" in the BIOS settings to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Upon rebooting the system, I noticed that the graphics driver did not load properly. The immediate indication was a drop in resolution from 1440p to 1024 x 768. Disabling the SVM mode resolved the issue. Nonetheless, I would like to be able to enable SVM mode. While searching online, I came across a suggestion to disable IOMMU, but for some reason, this setting reverts to "Auto" after each reboot.

What steps can I take to ensure that I can enable virtualization while ensuring that the graphics driver loads successfully? Just to clarify, my PC is connected to the monitor using an HDMI cable. Once again, everything works fine when SVM mode is disabled.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I did. How do I enable AMD-V? I did a quick search online and people say I need to enable SVM in BIOS to enable AMD-V. Currently, when I launch Ubuntu, the command window shows "Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.".

Comment: I installed it by running ```wsl --install```. Not by enabling the optional feature.

Comment: That's not the question I asked in the OP.

Comment: Ok. You are right.